# Принцип подстановки Лисков

Tags: c#, solid

Принцип, описывает 3 правила:

> Предусловия (Preconditions) не могут быть усилены в подклассе. Другими
>   словами подклассы не должны создавать больше предусловий, чем это
>   определено в базовом классе, для выполнения некоторого поведения
>
> Постусловия (Postconditions) не могут быть ослаблены в подклассе. То
>   есть подклассы должны выполнять все постусловия, которые определены в
>   базовом классе.
>
> Инварианты (Invariants) — все условия базового класса - также должны
>   быть сохранены и в подклассе

Вроде, все логично, но не понимаю, что в таком случае вооще можно делать при наследовании, что бы не нарушить данный принцип...

Например, вот пример с метанита:
Усиление предусловия:

```
class Account
{
    public int Capital { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void SetCapital(int money)
    {
        if (money < 0)
            throw new Exception("Нельзя положить на счет меньше 0");
        this.Capital = money;
    }
}

class MicroAccount : Account
{
    public override void SetCapital(int money)
    {
        if (money < 0)
            throw new Exception("Нельзя положить на счет меньше 0");

        if (money > 100)
            throw new Exception("Нельзя положить на счет больше 100");

        this.Capital = money;
    }
}
```

Ослабление постусловия:

```
class Account
{
    public virtual decimal GetInterest(decimal sum,  int month, int rate)
    {
        // предусловие
        if (sum < 0 || month >12 || month <1 || rate <0)
            throw new Exception("Некорректные данные");

        decimal result = sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < month; i++)
            result += result * rate  / 100;

        // постусловие
        if (sum >= 1000)
            result += 100; // добавляем бонус

        return result;
    }
}

class MicroAccount : Account
{
    public override decimal GetInterest(decimal sum, int month, int rate)
    {
        if (sum < 0 || month > 12 || month < 1 || rate < 0)
            throw new Exception("Некорректные данные");

        decimal result = sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < month; i++)
            result += result * rate /100;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Что-то не понимаю, а что если в наследних мне действительно нужно изменить некоторое поведение?

Или вот есть интерфейс и 10-ок классов реализует этот интерфейс => они могут реализовать различное поведение, так как первоначальной реализации нет.

Comment: *"Или вот есть интерфейс и 10-ок классов реализует этот интерфейс => они могут реализовать различное поведение, так как первоначальной реализации нет."* - такая формулировка мне представляется в корне неправильной. Пре/пост условия и инварианты - это то, то является частью интерфейса (интерфейса в широком смысле). То бишь то, на что могут рассичитывать пользователи класса не залезая в его реализацию (то бишь без нарушения икнапсуляции).

Comment: @AlexanderChernin *"Пре и посткондишион это грубоговоря, про количество аргументов и из типы, и про возвращаемое значение"* - в языках с поддержкой программирования по контракту и ограничений это может быть все что угодно.

Comment: Этот принцип не про реализацию кода в методах, а про ненарушение их поведения для внешнего окружения. То есть, есть код который вызывает у объекта Аккаунт какой-либо метод, то и все наследники должны иметь такой же и с таким же поведением (но не реализацией). Пре и постусловия это, грубоговоря, про количество аргументов и их типы, и аналогично про возвращаемое значение

Comment: Как приятно видеть хоть один фундаментальный вопрос в общей куче.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот принцип уже обсужден много раз (например, [раз](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/09/liskov-substitution-principle.html), [два](https://blog.byndyu.ru/2009/10/blog-post_29.html), [три](http://blog.muradovm.com/2012/03/solid.html))

В общем случае он звучит как

> Функции, которые используют ссылки на базовые классы, должны иметь возможность использовать объекты производных классов, не зная об этом

Каким образом этого можно добиться?

Допустим, у вас есть интерфейс. И у этого интерфейса есть описание (образно говоря, контракт, то есть описание, что должны делать члены этого интерфейса), например вот [IList](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.8), возьмем его метод [Add](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?view=netframework-4.8)

> Добавляет элемент в коллекцию IList.
>
> Параметры
>   value
>   Object
>   Объект, добавляемый в коллекцию IList.
>
> Возвращаемое значение
>   Int32
>   Позиция, в которую вставлен новый элемент, или значение -1, если элемент не вставлен в коллекцию.

Здесь явно прописано поведение реализации. Таким образом, не важно, какую вы используете реализацию списка, метод должен принимать объект и возвращать индекс.

Как можно сломать предусловие? Очень просто

```
public int Add (object value)
{
    if (!(value is MyClass)) throw new ArgumentException();
    .....
}
```

В интерфейсе явно не прописано, что можно добавлять каие то особенные элементы, потому, клиенты этого интерфейса очень удивятся, если в этот необобщенный список можно будет добавлять не все объекты, что захочется.

Как сломать постусловие? Очень просто

```
public int Add (object value)
{        
    .....
    // вставка в коллекцию
    return -1;
}
```

В интерфейсе четко указано, что при успешной вставке в коллекцию, метод должен вернуть корректный индекс. Если мы нарушаем это правило - мы нарушаем контракт интерфйса.

Таким образом принцип подстановки Лисков говорит вам - вы можете реализовать как вы хотите ваши классы, но контракт интерфейса или базового класса вы должны сохранить. В таком случае, если существует уже написанный код, который оперирует с IList согласно контракту интерфейса, то вы можете подсунуть ему любую реализацию IList и код должен продолжать успешно работать.